# Obtaining a particular form of solution for an integral

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

When I do:

```
Integrate [E^(-(t/\[Tau])) Cos[\[Omega] t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

How could I get the solution in the form:

```
\[Tau]/(1 + \[Omega]^2*\[Tau]^2)
```

Comment: You have syntax errors.

Comment: And what's wrong? It returns the answer in `ConditionalExpression` form.

Comment: No, I am trying to verify the solution of the definite integral in a paper but Mathematica does not give it in this form?

Answer (score 1):

As has already been commented the integral is correct.
You can get the form you want in a number of ways:

```
a=Integrate [E^(-(t/\[Tau])) Cos[\[Omega] t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}];
a[[1]]
```

As per @Nasser:

```
 Assuming[Abs[Im[\[Omega]]] < Re[1/\[Tau]], Integrate[E^(-(t/\[Tau])) Cos[\[Omega] t],

{t, 0, Infinity}]]
```

Or,

```
Integrate[E^(-(t/\[Tau])) Cos[\[Omega] t], {t, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> Abs[Im[\[Omega]]] < Re[1/\[Tau]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is (at least) one more way:

```
Integrate[E^(-(t/τ)) Cos[ω t], {t, 0, Infinity}, 
 GenerateConditions -> False]
(* τ/(1 + τ^2 ω^2) *)
```